# The request for procedure 'x' failed because 'x' is a table valued function object. при выполнении процедуры

Tags: node.js, sql-server, execute

При выполнении процедуры в Node.js:

> The request for procedure 'x' failed because 'x' is a table valued function object.

Для работы с MSSQL использую [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Функция с табличным значением  принимает id и возвращает таблицу.
Выполняю вот так:

```
export const dboUdfConfigCompliance = async (id: string) => {
try {
  const pool = await connectDB();
  return await pool
   ?.request()
   .input('SrvId', sql.Int, id)
   .execute('[dbo].[udfConfigCompliance]');
 } catch (err: any | unknown) {
  throw new HandlerErr(`Ошибка выполнения процедуры [dbo].[udfConfigCompliance] ${err.message}`);
 }
};
```

Предистория - старый фронт был на C# и запросы к бд были напрямую с фронта. Я переношу логику работы с БД на node.js

Comment: нужно выполнить select * from [dbo].[udfConfigCompliance], соответственно через cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Понять бы еще, как это сделать через node.js

Comment: Все операторы SQL выполняются с помощью функции new Request() . Если оператор, например select, возвращает строки, их можно извлечь с помощью функции request.on() . Если строк нет, функция request.on() возвращает пустые списки. тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выполнять процедуру через .query, а не .execute.

```
`export const dboUdfConfigCompliance = async (id: string) => {
    try {
        const pool = await connectDB();
        return await pool
    ?.request()
    .input('SrvId', sql.Int, id)
    .query('SELECT ....);
    } catch (err: any | unknown) {
        throw new HandlerErr(`Ошибка выполнения процедуры [dbo].[udfConfigCompliance] ${err.message}`);
    }
};
};`
```